# iOS Enterprise Distribution vs AppStore - why separate install with SAME BundleID

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I have an app that I build for Enterprise Distro and also submit to the AppStore. Same app code, same bundleID used. Obviously all thats different is the Team Account used and provisioning profile (Enterprise profile vs the AppStore's automatic signing profile). Why when I install the enterprise app OTA and then install it off the AppStore do I get 2 separate app installs (with the same name)? I thought BundleID was the key to "app install uniqueness" in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the bundle ID is silently prepended by a team identifier, much like your provisioning profile, e.g. 5Y7Q769X9.*

Apple does this sometimes with the Bundle identifier, I couldn't tell you where exactly but I've seen it.

[image: See the prefix]

Comment: I suspect you're right. I'm hoping someone knows for sure :) Thats def the case (TeamID+BundleID) to get a final ID Apple calls they an AppID, but from what I read that's not about identifying on a particular device, but more of a dev team provisioning thing. Still, something odd is going on there...

Comment: Marking as answer since testing with AppStore vs Enterprise Distro seems to back up this theory. Still would like it confirmed from someone who knows for sure though

Comment: Wouldn't we all. If you don't use it you could use one of your two yearly support tickets.